# Is there any possibility of decreasing extra space before the equation when line nearly breaks in the following?

Tags: spacing, equations, line-breaking

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
Preliminary Theorem 1.1.2. If $(\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n)$, $(\mu_1,...,\mu_n)$, 
and $(k_1,...,k_n)$ are arrangements of $(1,...,n),$ then \begin{flalign*}
&\epsilon\bordermatrix{&\cr&\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n \cr&\mu_1,...,\mu_n 
\cr}=\epsilon\bordermatrix{&\cr&\lambda_{k_1},...,\lambda_{k_1} \cr&\mu_{k_1},...,\mu_n \cr}. \end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that `\bordermatrix` is a very special construction, which shouldn't generally be used, unless you really need to add names for rows and columns; the extra vertical space you get is exactly the space reserved for the column names.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You better use `pmatrix`:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
Preliminary Theorem 1.1.2. If $(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n)$, $(\mu_1,\dots,\mu_n)$,
and $(k_1,\dots,k_n)$ are arrangements of $(1,\dots,n),$ then
\begin{align*}
&ϵ\begin{pmatrix}
     \lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n \\
     \mu_1,\dots,\mu_n
  \end{pmatrix}=ϵ
    \begin{pmatrix}
    \lambda_{k_1},\dots,\lambda_{k_1} \\
    \mu_{k_1},\dots,\mu_n
  \end{pmatrix}.
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Use `\dots` and not `...`

Comment: @egreg Yes, I always overlook something!, may be I am too focussed ;-). Thanks for noting.

Comment: To Harish, 
Thank you so very much for your demonstration. The BEST part of your illustration is the introduction of pmatrix. I did not know it for I am new to LaTex. Once again thank you!